# Ошибка при преобразовании char в int c#

Tags: c#, .net

Вот код:

```
Console.WriteLine(int('b'));
```

Я всего лишь хочу преобразовать char в тип int, что в языке Си делалось без проблем, почему сейчас возникает следующая ошибка?

> Недопустимый термин "int" в выражении

Comment: `Console.WriteLine((int)'b');`?

Comment: Причём здесь `Visual Studio`? Пойдите дальше! Добавьте метки `Windows`, `PC`, `Intel` (или какой у Вас там процессор). Это все имеет непосредственное отношение к делу! Ведь если я набираю C#-код в Sublime, то это совершенно иной код, нежели я набирал бы в VS! Используйте метки правильно, не надо их перегружать ненужной информацией

Comment: @Kir_Antipov воу воу, полегче :) Специально для вас я поправил метки вопроса.

Comment: @tym32167: :D Да просто люди имеют свойство ставить метки, которые вообще к вопросу не относятся. Некоторые туда готовы адрес своего проживания вписать, ибо вдруг это как-то влияет на их код ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kir_Antipov на сетевые проблемы адрес проживания вполне может влиять=)

Comment: @iluxa1810: но явно не на приведение char к int :)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov это скорее проблема неосознанной компетентности. То, что вам кажется очевидным, может вызывать затруднения у других, менее опытных участников. Я тут недавно нашел свои вопросы в интернете, которые я задавал 11 лет назад и понял, что надо терпимее относиться к неопытным коллегам :)

Comment: В C/C++ много неявных преобразований, которых нет в C#. Например, преобразование чисел/указателей к логическому типу в плюсах есть, а в шарпе придется писать `!= 0` и `!= null`. Для своих типов данных вы можете определить неявное преобразование, но для встроенных нет.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov еще знаменитую метку [tag:microsoft] упомянуть забыли.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, понял, буду стараться не ставить лишних меток

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно сделать явное преобразование

```
int val = (int) 'b';    
Console.WriteLine(val);
```

[Преобразование типов в .NET Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/type-conversion)